# "Google Maps Platform rejected your request" error when trying to use Google Map Embed API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-cloud-platform

Just sharing because I couldn't find any information on this error, and I wanted the solution to be out there.

I was trying to embed a map on my website using Google Map Embed API, but I kept getting the following error, no matter what I did with my App permissions:

> Google Maps Platform rejected your request. You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs. For additional information, please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account

My map src url was structured like so:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=Washington,DC&key=[API Key]
```

and it seemed to match the guidelines, so I couldn't figure out what was wrong.

Answer (score -1):

I can't find this anywhere in the documentation, but it's this simple - the key params is supposed to be first.

Just turn this:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=Washington,DC&key=[API Key]
```

into this:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=[API KEY]&q=Washington,DC
```

and now it works.

Comment: The original order works for me: [example](http://www.geocodezip.com/example_embedded_map_20150812.html)

Comment: @geocodezip That link just takes me to a google maps error. Did you whitelist your ip address?

Comment: It works for me (from work, inside a firewall), not sure why it doesn't work for you.